# Regex - Match specific string, start value, end value and everything in between

Tags: regex

I have a string like:

```
<abc=1 def =2 value='thevalue' othervalue='fjgfjf' ghi=4><rte=1 tyuy=2 value='uyrdu' othervalue='sruhhh' ghi=43><gffsd=1 ewre=2 value='evff' othervalue='zsds' gfg=43>
```

I need a regex expression that would match the string that contains 'thevalue' including the starting '<' and closing '>'. So, in the example above, the regex would match:

```
<abc=1 def =2 value='thevalue' othervalue='fjgfjf' ghi=4>
```

The string to be matched would always begin with '<' and end with '>'. However, I need the entire string, including the opening '<' and closing '>' matched. Any ideas?

Comment: Community expects to see the least made attempt(s) from OP. Please include it.

Comment: Try: <[^>]*'thevalue'[^>]*>

Comment: I apologize for not posting my attempts but I didn't want post to go sideways by analyzing my failed attempts. Not trying to be a leech. I will update the post shortly. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
(<[^>]*thevalue[^>]*>)
```

**Explanation:**

`(` begins a capture group

`<` matches an opening bracket

`[^>]*` greedily matches zero or more characters that are not a closing bracket

`thevalue` matches "thevalue"

`[^>]*` greedily matches zero or more characters that are not a closing bracket

`>` matches the closing bracket

`)` ends the capture group

Comment: Thanks for this explanation. I did not understand the syntax for how "greedily matches zero or more characters" works. But, now that it has been explained in context...I get it. Thanks.